# Turning a phone number array into individual numbers then comparing the numbers javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a program that compares the summed digits of a phone number and returns the largest. The thing is my code was long and I know it can be made more simple using a loop to run the numbers through. I am new to programing and when I put it in a loop it says "syntax error" however, I don't know exactly what my syntax error is. My ultimate goal is to make a function that asks the user "how many numbers are you comparing" then uses the user answer to the question to loop through the program that many times and each time it loops through it compares if the phone number is larger then the current largest and if so replaces a variable called largest number with the new number and then it keeps going through however many times and in the end returns the largest phone number. 
I am not there yet... So what I am hoping to do right now if figure out how to make the loop itself take the user prompt for phone numbers and run through adding them. After that I will worry about how to save the number and compare them. Here is what I have:

```
var numbers = prompt("How many phone numbers would you like to 
compare?");
For (i=0; i=numbers; i++) {
  var PhoneNumber[i]= prompt("Give me a 10 digit phone number separated by dashes for example 234-234-2342");
  var num1 = PhoneNumber.substring(0, 1);
  var num2=  PhoneNumber.substring(1, 2);
  var num3=  PhoneNumber.substring(2, 3);
  var num4=  PhoneNumber.substring(4, 5);
  var num5=  PhoneNumber.substring(5, 6);
  var num6=  PhoneNumber.substring(6, 7);
  var num7=  PhoneNumber.substring(8, 9);
  var num8=  PhoneNumber.substring(9, 10);
  var num9=  PhoneNumber.substring(10, 11);
  var num10=  PhoneNumber.substring(11, 12);
  PhoneNumberTotal[i] = (+num1 + +num2 + +num3 + +num4 + +num5 + +num6 + +num7 + +num8 + +num9 + +num10);
  console.log(PhoneNumberTotal[i];
};
```

This is just to get the phone number totals then I will worry about comparing them but this says error and really I have no idea what I am doing so I am sure it is messy. Please help!

Comment: You can actually access strings like accessing arrays using the `[]` notation - that will be the first thing to improve (: So `.substring(0,1)` can simply be `[1]`. Heres where a `for` loop will be handy.

Comment: `var numArray = PhoneNumber[i].replace(/-/g,"").split("");`

Comment: No, start by working through some basic JavaScript tutorials. There are far too many issues with the code above for a single SO question. 1. `For` should be `for` 2. All the logic is *inside* the loop, when most of it is clearly meant to be outside it. 3. `var PhoneNumber[i]` 4. `substring` on what's meant to be an array. That's just at a glance. No one is born knowing any programming language; study is required. That's fine, no shame in that. But you need to **do** that study, and then come back with specific questions.

Comment: console.log(...) <<<

Comment: Thanks mplugjan but the thing I don't get is if I don't use a loop and I ask for user prompt for 3 phone numbers and run the code with the substrings 3 times then put it in an if then statement to compare the summed totals it works. It is true that I don't know how to put it into a loop but I finished code academy's loop section and it clearly didn't help. How do I know what "clearly" goes outside the loop or in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var numbers = prompt("How many phone numbers would you like to compare?");

  var PhoneNumber=[];
  var PhoneNumberTotal=[];
  var maxSum=0,maxIndex;

  //For is not right, it should be for
  // i is not declared
  // i<numbers , each time this condition is checked

  for(var i=0; i<numbers; i++) 
  {
    PhoneNumber[i]= prompt("Give me a 10 digit phone number separated  by dashes for example 234-234-2342");

    //remove dashes from the number and store in tempVar
    // "/-/g" is regular expression which says identify all dashes in any thing
    // read something about it
    var tempVar=PhoneNumber[i].replace(/-/g,'');
    PhoneNumberTotal[i]=0;
    for(var j=0;j<tempVar.length;j++)
     {

        var jthCharOfTempVar=tempVar.charAt(j);
        //convert string to integer and sum to PhoneNumberTotal[i]
        PhoneNumberTotal[i]= PhoneNumberTotal[i]+parseInt(jthCharOfTempVar);

     }

    if(PhoneNumberTotal[i]>maxSum)
      {
         maxSum=PhoneNumberTotal[i];
         maxIndex=i;

      }
 }


 console.log("Greatest Number",PhoneNumber[maxIndex]);
 console.log("SumOf digits",PhoneNumberTotal[i]);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh this is great! I didn't realize that you could replace the dashes with spaces so easily! Also, do you always need to set the variables = to an array outside the function before prompting for one? I don't understand why you have to do that but it was very helpful to see. Thank you!

Comment: If this solves your problem then please acknowledge my effort by accepting the answer. This keeps me motivated. If any doubt feel free to ask.. @user5712236

Comment: @user5712236. when you prompt something like prompt("enter some value"), you get some value entered by the user. That value you need to store some where, so that you  can access it later.

Comment: I declared phoneNumber array because each time user enters the number it is stored in the array with index.  so you can access the ith phone number by saying phonenumber[i].. The arrray should be out of loop because so that you can access it outside of loop also,only insertion to the array is happenig inside the loop. if you declare a variable insid loop then each time the lop executes it will be rewritten and you only get the value has been set by the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, using some very simple Javascript features.

```
var numbers = prompt("How many phone numbers would you like to compare?");
// Use < here. Using = would give 1 too many numbers.  For loops are lowercase.
for (var i=0; i<numbers; i++) {
  var PhoneNumber[i] = prompt("Give me a 10 digit phone number separated by dashes for example 234-234-2342");
  // Loop through the digits
  for (var j=0; j<number.length; j++) {
    // Skip dashes.
    if ( j == 3 || j == 7 ) continue;
    // Add digit to total, parsed as number.
    PhoneNumberTotal[i] += (+number[j]);
  }
  console.log(PhoneNumberTotal[i]); // Needs closing parenth
};
```

For an much shorter implementation, you can use something like this:

```
// replace: remove dashes
// split: turn string into array of chars
// reduce: loop and add each digit to sum, then return
var numbers = prompt("How many phone numbers would you like to compare?");
for (var i=0; i<numbers; i++) {
  var PhoneNumber[i] = prompt("Give me a 10 digit phone number separated by dashes for example 234-234-2342");
  PhoneNumberTotal[i] = PhoneNumber[i]
    .replace(/-/g,"")
    .split("")
    .reduce(function(sum, digit) { return sum + (+digit); }, 0);
  console.log(PhoneNumberTotal[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will sum all digits in the string:

```
function sumNumber(numStr) {
  return numStr.match(/\d/g).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Number(a) + Number(b);
  });
}
```

And now, all you need to do is compare numbers.

```
var numbers = prompt("How many phone numbers would you like to compare?"), 
    biggestPhone = { total : '0'},
    numStr, sum;

for(var i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
   numStr = prompt("Give me a 10 digit phone number separated by dashes for example 234-234-2342");
   sum = sumNumber(numStr);
   if(sum > biggestPhone.total) biggestPhone = { total : sum, number : numStr };
}

alert('Biggest number is ' + biggestPhone.number + ' which totals to: ' + biggestPhone.total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using all of the wonderful suggestions but not wanting to stray too much from my original code I was able to solve this problem. Incase anyone else is in the same boat as myself I am posting my solution which works for the purpose that I was making the code for even if it is not what everyone suggested and if it is not the 'best' looking code around.

```
    var numbers = prompt("How many phone numbers would you like to   
    compare?");

   var PhoneNumber=[];
   var PhoneNumberTotal=[];
   var maxSum=0,maxIndex;

   for(var i=0; i<numbers; i++) {
   PhoneNumber[i]= prompt("Give me a 10 digit phone number separated  by    
   dashes for example 234-234-2342");
   var num1 = PhoneNumber[i].substring(0, 1); 
   var num2=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(1, 2);
   var num3=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(2, 3);
   var num4=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(4, 5);
   var num5=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(5, 6);
   var num6=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(6, 7);
   var num7=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(8, 9);
   var num8=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(9, 10);
   var num9=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(10, 11);
   var num10=  PhoneNumber[i].substring(11, 12);
  PhoneNumberTotal= +num1 + +num2 + +num3 + +num4 + +num5 + +num6 + +num7   
  + +num8 + +num9 + +num10;


      if(PhoneNumberTotal>maxSum)
      {
         maxSum=PhoneNumberTotal;
         maxIndex=i;

      }
   };


   console.log("Greatest Number",PhoneNumber[maxIndex]);
   console.log("SumOf digits",PhoneNumberTotal);
```